# Excel - exporting as csv and saving to another location

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a command button in Excel, but after a lot of searching and trying different codes on the internet I can't seem to find one that suits my personal needs.
I want this to happen after I press the button:

- Export and save the opened Excel file to another file location, I.e. c:/test.
- The name of the document should be the same as the Excel file.

So far the best code I have found after scavenging the internet is this. The problem is that the end user has to physically press "save" in order to save the file.

```
Dim folderPath As String
Dim csvFile As String

folderPath = "C:\Users\username\Documents"

csvFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=folderPath, _
            FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Save As CSV")

If csvFile <> "" And csvFile <> "False" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=csvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=xlUserResolution
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Close .csv workbook, leaving original workbook open
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try the next simplified code. The user does not have to press anything, except to run the code. It will anyhow save only the active sheet:

```
Sub SaveCSV()
 Dim folderPath As String, csvFile As String

 folderPath = "C:\test"
 'if test folder does not exist, it will be created:
 If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir folderPath
 'The csv file name is obtained by replacing the active workbook extension:
 csvFile = folderPath & "\" & Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) & ".csv"

  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=csvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV

  ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! :) Really appreciate it.
I still have two small small problems left, when the workbook is saved as a csv:
-  it is not possible to continue to work on the file after the button is pressed, Does it have to do with ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False ?
- If there already exists a file in the folder named the document name, I want it do automatically to be written over, instead of the dialogue frame opening up and asking to write over the file name.

Comment: @Stormtalon: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the solution works... :)